# 'tns' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, tns

I am new to NativeScript and am currently going through the installation steps described here (http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1) and I just completed executing the PowerShell script

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/production/setup/native-script.ps1'))"
```

and then I run

```
tns doctor
```

and I get

```
 C:\>tns doctor 'tns' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: this is step 3 in the tutoriall... step 2 is instaliing tns - did you run the command "npm install -g nativescript"  (in order to run npm you shouyld have installed Node.js version 4.x or 5.x)

Comment: In my case I have already installed nativescript using the command above and now attempting to run the same command seems to make npm hang.

Answer (score 13):

Use this code

```
npm install --global nativescript
```

I had the same isssue and installing `nativescript` solved it.

Comment: This is an answer. I had the same problem and I solved it by installing nativescript globally

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation and I will revise my review.

Comment: Cant able to install tns. as tns required node8.x and Node team officially ended node 8 support

Answer (score 8):

If you are on Windows you need to add the the npm global directory to your path.

1. Control Panels -> System
2. Advanced System Settings (Link on Left side)
3. Environmental Variables (Button)
4. Scroll down for Path, and then click Edit (Button)
5. Append to the end: `;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Make sure you get the semicolon.

This should work on Windows 7.   I can get you the steps for other versions of windows; but hopefully this gets you going.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to create a mobile app with angular using nativescript and Install angular module `npm install --global @nativescript/schematics`

followed all instruction as mention in https://blog.angular.io/apps-that-work-natively-on-the-web-and-mobile-9b26852495e7

after everything, I faced the same error.

'tns' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

But it got resolved by installing nativescript module globally.

**npm install --global nativescript**

or

**npm install -g nativescript**

After that, I was able to use **tns** properly.

Hope this will help you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Users\\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` (replace `username` appropriately) and check if Nativescript is installed or not. If not create directory and install nativescript and copy nativescript dir from node_modules and paste inside `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

create C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\**tns.cmd** file and copy below content

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
    "%~dp0\node.exe" "%~dp0\node_modules\nativescript\bin\tns" %*
) ELSE (
    @SETLOCAL
    @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
    node "%~dp0\node_modules\nativescript\bin\tns" %*
)
```